# Custom Validation on Text Field Contact Form 7

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying to validate a text field that only accepts a valid date e.g. 21-03-1980 however the validation code is not being triggered but I can't see what is wrong.

Here is the code I am using:

```
function custom_dob_validation_filter($result,$tag){

    $name = $tag->name;

    if($name == 'datemdy'){

        $datemdy = $_POST['datemdy'];

        if($datemdy != '') {

            if(!preg_match('/^([0-9]{1,2})\\/([0-9]{1,2})\\/([0-9]{4})$/', $datemdy)) {

                $result->invalidate( $tag, "Please Enter a Valid Date of Birth" );

            }

        }

    }

    return $result;
}   

add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_dob*', 'custom_dob_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_dob', 'custom_dob_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

Comment: You might consider using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) instead of a regex to validate the date. This part in your regex `\\/` should be `-` like `^([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{4})$`

Comment: Perhaps `$datemdy` has some spaces at the beginning/end?

Comment: Is the 'add_filter' line twice on purpose or by mistake?

Comment: This is on purpose to include validation for the normal and required version of the input

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching I have found the issue.

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_dob*', 'custom_dob_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_dob', 'custom_dob_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
```

Should be replaced with:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'custom_dob_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text', 'custom_dob_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
```